# Is it posible to use System.Configuration to Write to a Network Location

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, system.configuration

due to our applications being moved onto a Citrix VM platform I need to move our application settings config files from C:\ProgramData to an alternative location.  With this particular application each user has their own config file, which is effectively a clone of the app.config file but with just user specific content, for example encrypted authentication credentials.

With this in mind, I modified the code to save the config files to a mapped network drive.  Using system.configuration I am able to read content without any issues from the networked drive but when I attempt to write changes I get the following error message:

*"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."

The following is the function which generates the error:

```
    Public Shared Function WriteSettingUser(ByVal configPath As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal sectionName As String, ByVal setting As String, ByVal value As String) As String
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        Dim filemap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap
        Dim config As Configuration
        Dim section As AppSettingsSection

        Try

            filemap.ExeConfigFilename = configPath & userName & ".config"
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(filemap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
            section = config.GetSection(sectionName)
            section.Settings(setting).Value = value
            config.Save()
            result = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
            result = False
        Finally

        End Try

        Return result
```

The error is generated at the 'config.save' line.

Would appreciate any insight into this issue.

Kind Regards
Paul J.